# Display text when timer reaches 0s, and add 0 before 1-9s

Tags: javascript

I want to display some text once the timer goes to  0:00, and when the timer is anywhere in between 1-9s, I want to display a 0 in front of the seconds, e.g. `1:04` instead of `1: 4`. How would I do this?

```
const timeSpan = document.getElementById('timer');
var sec = 600 / 60;
const mins = sec;
const now = new Date().getTime();
const deadline = mins * 60 * 1000 + now;


setInterval(() => {
  var currentTime = new Date().getTime();
  var distance = deadline - currentTime;
  var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);


  timeSpan.innerHTML = minutes + ':' + seconds;
  
}, 500)
```

Comment: `seconds = seconds < 10 ? '0' + seconds : seconds`.

Comment: *"what to do to display text"*: which text are you referring to? Where is your attempt to display any text?

Comment: On the spot of the timer something like "You can claim points"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can:

- Check `minutes+seconds <= 0`. If this is true, the count down reached 0. You can use this condition to output a custom string.
- Get a the id of the timer from the call to `setInterval` and use it to stop the timer when the delay is zero.
- Format the output by replacing single digits with double digits, using a regular expression. There are many other ways to do this.

```js
const timeSpan = document.getElementById('timer');
const mins = 6 / 60; // For the demo I shortened the deadline
const now = new Date().getTime();
const deadline = mins * 60 * 1000 + now;

// Get the timer identifier
let timer = setInterval(() => {
  var currentTime = new Date().getTime();
  var distance = deadline - currentTime;
  var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

  if (minutes+seconds <= 0) { // The delay is 0
      timeSpan.innerHTML = "You can claim points";
      clearInterval(timer); // Stop the timer
  } else {
      // Replace single digits with double digits
      timeSpan.innerHTML = (minutes + ':' + seconds).replace(/\b\d\b/g, "0$&");
  }
}, 500);
```

```html
<span id="timer"></span>
```

Comment: Thank You, It work well